# SMTP python traceback error when trying to connect

Tags: python, smtp

So I'm getting this error:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
   return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Not entirely sure why :s Could anyone help me out a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect 'localhost', port 25 (the default values for [`.connect()`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.connect)), and there is no server listening there. Thus the connection is refused.

Answer (score 0):

[This has a good example usage of how to use smtp with python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email)

Link: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email